# Apache only allow index.php - not working from root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security

I have Apache 2.4 web server for PHP and I want to make it secure using .htaccess, so that noone will be able to access my files other than `index.php` in root folder (`var/www/html/index.php`). The problem is that with my configuration it allows index.php only from `localhost/index.php` and not `localhost/`. I tried redirecting but it doesn't change much:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Redirect the root (/) to index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]

# Deny all requests by default
Require all denied

# Allow only access to index.php
<Files "index.php">
  Require all granted
</Files>
```

Comment: Take a look at the `DirectoryIndex` directive in the documentation.

Comment: @arkascha from what I am reading, it should execute index.php - that's why I'm so confused I get 403 forbidden with and without `DirectoryIndex`

Comment: Then you have another issue. Not rewriting or defining the correct index script. But a general authorization issue. You will have to check your central apache configuration for how that is set up. Keep in mind that anything in a _distributed_ configuration file, so what people usually name ".htaccess", comes after the central configuration and is only applied if enabled in the central configuration.

Comment: And, by the way, don't you think that what you revealed now should have been an information you give in the question itself? There is an "edit" button below it. _Use it ..._

Comment: I thought it's enough if I mentioned `DirectoryIndex` in my question and said that with this specific whole file (including `DirectoryIndex`) is not working. Anyway I found a way to solve my issue (posted it as an answer).

Comment: I'd say the fact that you received back a 403 is something completely different than what I understood from your question, that the rewriting did not work.

Comment: But that is an interesting result you posted. Congratulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing

```
<Files "index.php">
  Require all granted
</Files>
```

to

```
<Files ~ "^(index\.php|)$">
  Require all granted
</Files>
```

fixes the issue;

`<Files ~ "^(index\.php|)$">`:

- `~` indicates regex
- then we are searching for `index.php` or empty string (which is root directory in this case)